# Python packages not installing or upgrading

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip

For the past hours i have been trying to install numpy, pandas, and other python libraries without succes. I tried upgrading pip but the sdame error pops up. I tried doing it directly through the package installer in pycharm but it still brings up the same error. Here is the code that pops after inatallation/upgrading fails:

```
C:\Users\clark>pip install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after
connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed 

ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 526, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 466, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1278, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1134, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 400, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 536, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 621, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 559, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I was trying to install/upgrade a package but an error popped up impeding me to install or upgrade anything in python.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @topsail that's not the issue - `pip` is smart enough to fall back to a user install if it can't write to the global `site-packages`. If you look at the error that the OP did include, you'll see there's at least something going on with SSL. I'd hazard a guess and say PyPI is not reachable. They've been [targeted by a lot of bad actors lately](https://status.python.org/incidents/qy2t9mjjcc7g), perhaps this is the next step. Or it could be something else, without the complete traceback it's all just guesswork.

Comment: code was edited for full view of error.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like my initial suspicion was correct - `pip` is unable to communicate with either pypi.org or files.pythonhosted.org, or potentially both. `pip` is working fine for me here (near Boston in the northeast US), so I'm not sure what's going on. Check your VPN, if you're using one, or your proxy if you're using one, or your internet service provider to see if they're experiencing outages.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: thanks a lot. Maybe my internet connectin is the problem. I am in a remote area and the internet sucks. likewise, i am installing anaconda now, seems like the solution.

Comment: FWIW if all you want is to use anaconda for managing python environments, [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) is all you need (and a whole lot smaller).

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you so much, this solved my problem and made me find out about this anaconda. thanks :)